# SQL query to determine if groups of rows have a particular value in a particular column

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2016.  I have the following table and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    col1 char(1)
    ,col2 int
    ,indicator_flag char(4)
)
;

INSERT INTO A
VALUES
('A', 1, 'Pass')
,('A', 2, 'Pass')
,('A', 3, 'Fail')
,('B', 10, 'Pass')
,('C', 19, 'Fail')
,('D', 1, 'Fail')
,('D', 2, 'Fail')
,('E', 1, 'Pass')
,('E', 2, 'Pass')
,('F', 20, 'Fail')
,('F', 21, 'Fail')
,('F', 100, 'Pass')
;
```

The `indicator_flag` column will only ever hold values 'Pass' and 'Fail'.  For every distinct value in `col1`, I want to return a collapsed `indicator_flag` value according to the following rule -- if all values are 'Pass', then 'Pass'; else, 'Fail'.

So, for the sample data, I expect the following output:

```
col1        collapsed_indicator_flag
A           Fail
B           Pass
C           Fail
D           Fail
E           Pass
F           Fail
```

How can I achieve this output?  The solution needs to perform well.  (My actual table is very large.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use aggregation:

```
select col1, min(indicator_flag) as indicator_flag
from a
group by col1;
```

This uses the observation that `'Pass'` > `'Fail'`.

If you want performance, then you could speed this up if you have the right indexes and another table with just `col1` values:

```
select t.col1, coalesce(a.indicator_flag, 'Pass') as indicator_flag
from col1table t outer apply
     (select a.*
      from a
      where a.col1 = t.col1 and a.indicator_flag = 'Fail'
     ) a;
```

The index for this query would be `a(col1, indicator_flag)`.